# Chrome Extension Upload Stream to S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use S3  multipart upload to upload data to S3 using a stream on the client-side.

I'm using [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to convert the Nodejs code into a single file that can be loaded by the Chrome Extension.

Here is my code:

```
    const Stream = require('stream');
    var inputBytesReadable = new Stream.Readable();
    // add data to the Stream
    var s3 = new AWS.S3({
                    params: {Bucket: bucketName}
                });
    var params = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: fileName,
      PartNumber: partNumber, 
      UploadId: uploadId, 
      Body: inputBytesReadable
    };
    s3.uploadPart(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err)
      {
          appendMessage("Error in uploading "+fileName+"part "+partNumber);
          console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      }
    });
```

However, this results in the error: **InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Body to be a string, Buffer, Stream, Blob, or typed array object**

What am I doing incorrectly? Is there any way that I can pass a Stream to S3 in client-side JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the AWS JavaScript SDK does not support stream inputs unless it is used in a Node.js environment. There is a specific environment check to enable this validation.

Therefore, it seems that it is not possible to use streams with the AWS SDK on the front end.